# I want to pass counter value to my component using props

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass counter  value to my component using props. I do not know how i should pass counter value.  Here is my component counter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }

    increment(props) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1
        }))

        console.log(this.state.count)
    }

    incrementFive() {
        this.increment()
        this.increment()
        this.increment()
        this.increment()
        this.increment()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div> Count - {this.state.count}</div>
                <button onClick={() => this.incrementFive()}>Increment</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter
```

I used my Counter component in App.js like below

```
<Counter></Counter>
```

Comment: This is literally nearly one of the examples in the react `setState` [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for using a functional update. FYI, the console.log after `setState` will always display the count value from *before* the update is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should follow this example. Please check it.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }

    increment(props) {
        this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
            count: prevState.count + props.incrementBy
        }));
        console.log(this.state.count)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div> Count - {this.state.count}</div>
                <button onClick={() => this.increment()}>Increment</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

In you App.js, you should write:

```
<Counter incrementBy={5}/>
```